# VFPOLEDB как пользоваться

Tags: c#, dbf

Как пользваться? Как написать запрос вида выбрать колонки время в dbf файле? файл лежит e:\analiz.dbf, пишу так

```
  String strConnection = @"provider=VFPOLEDB.1 ;data source='E:\ANALIZ.DBF';password='';user id=''";
        OleDbConnection VFP7Connection = new OleDbConnection();
        VFP7Connection.ConnectionString = strConnection;
        VFP7Connection.Open();

        String strSelect = "SELECT  PRODUKT, NOMER, FEMGN, FEOBS, DATA, TIME FROM ANALIZ";
        OleDbCommand VFP7SelectCommand = new
        OleDbCommand(strSelect, VFP7Connection);

        // Create a DataAdapter.
        OleDbDataAdapter VFP9DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        VFP9DataAdapter.SelectCommand = VFP7SelectCommand;

        // Create a DataSet.
        DataSet VFP7DataSet = new DataSet();

        // Fill the DataSet with table information.
        int iRecFound;
        iRecFound = VFP9DataAdapter.Fill(VFP7DataSet, "Customer");

        VFP7DataSet.Reset();
        VFP9DataAdapter.Fill(VFP7DataSet);
        DT = VFP7DataSet.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
```

он ругается + Перехвачено: "Поставщик не смог определить значение Decimal. Например, строка только что была создана, значение по умолчанию для столбца Decimal не было доступно, а потребитель еще не задал нового значения Decimal." (System.InvalidOperationException)